# Sum of Bounded Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that a series $\sum a_{n}$ is bounded if $\sup_{n} |\sum a_{n}| < \infty$. And a boundedness of series does not imply convergence unless its terms are monotonic. Convergence of series means that if partial sum of given series $ S_{m} =  \sum_{n=1}^{m}a_{n}$, $\lim_{m\to\infty}S_{m}$ exists. (That is $S_{m}<\infty$). My question is: can I say for any bounded sequence $\sup_{n}|\sum a_{n}|<\infty$ implies $\sum a_{n}<\infty$ but here I am not talking about convergence. Here is my example $\sum (-1)^n$ is bounded obviously and $\sup_{n}|\sum(-1)^n|=1$. So can I say $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n < \infty$. To be frankly, can I say that a sum of bounded series is less than infinity but the exact sum might be unknown.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I typeset your math formulas for you, but you may try it by yourself next time!

Comment: Thank you. Actually I know how to use some math typesetting program but I do not know how to put them here after write my question in those program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, because writing $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n$  means that the sequence of partial sum of that serie is convergent (and so it is a real number ; it is just a *particular notation for the limit of that sequence*). Actually, once you have proved that this sum is divergent, there is no sense to write  $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n$ because it is not well-defined.

Comment: ok. But isn't the sum in this example less than infinity. İt is either -1 or 0.

Comment: This sum does not exist, so you can't say anything about it. What you can say is :  $\sup_n\sum|a_n|<+\infty$ implies that $\sum a_n<+\infty,$ it is call absolute convergence (see the difference with the criterion you wanted to use).

Comment: I guess you are right since there is no exact sum I can not say anything:)

Comment: I put in italic in the answer the key-point (according to me) to understand series, I hope I helped you !

Comment: I have another question. Can you please take a look?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594199/matrix-transformation-of-bounded-sequence