# Matrix transformation of bounded sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

$A=(a_{nk})_{n,k=1}^\infty$ and $A_{n}(x)=∑_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{nk}x_{k}$ for fixed $n$. So $A_{n}(x)$ can be thought as a matrix transformation for any sequence. Now let $A∈(l_{\infty},l_{\infty})$ that is $\forall x \in l_{\infty}, A_{n}(x) \in l_{\infty}$. And $l_{\infty}$ represents bounded sequences. From here I get $\sup_{n}|A_{n}(x)|<\infty$ or $|A_{n}(x)|<\infty$, $\forall n$. By this transformation we find a new sequence $A_{n}(x)=(A_1(x),A_2(x),...)$ and supremum of this sequence is less than infinity. In this case can I say $A_{n}(x)=∑_{k=1}^{∞}a_{nk}x_{k}<\infty ,  \forall n$?

Comment: Note that you always have $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},|A_n(x)|_\infty<+\infty$ with your definition for $A,$ and that it is not the same assertion that $\sup_n|A_n(x)|_\infty<+\infty.$

Comment: can you please explain me why I always have ∀n∈N,|An(x)|∞<+∞ in this case?

Comment: Because you said that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},$ you have that $A_n$ maps any sequence $x\in l_\infty$ to an other sequence $A_n(x)\in l_\infty.$ As $l_\infty$ is the space of bounded sequences, then you have that for any sequence $y\in l_\infty,$ $|y|_\infty=\sup_n|y_n|<+\infty.$ So it is for $A_n(x).$

Comment: since ∀n∈N,|An(x)|∞<+∞ then   ∀n∈N,An(x)<+∞ please correct me:)) thats all I am looking for.

Comment: This last point is true, but it seems I have misunderstood something : it is not $A_n(x)\in l_\infty$ but $(A_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in l_\infty.$ But it does'nt change the conclusion which is that $|(A_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|_\infty<+\infty$ and in particular each term of this sequence is smaller than $+\infty.$